# Is there a way to set arbitrary characters as the word boundary?

Tags: syntax-table, words

I know I can do this kind of thing with the sentence boundary, using (setq sentence-end "[regexp]"), but how can I do this with the word boundary?

I'd like to add capital letters to the default word boundary symbol sets, so that I could use forward word command from the beginning of the line below to select only the "set".

```
setWordBoundary blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 8):

Here are two possibilities:

- Use [**`subword-mode`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/MixedCase-Words.html).  It is designed to do what you request.

  > Emacs’s word commands recognize upper case letters in
  >   `StudlyCapsIdentifiers` as word boundaries.  When Subword mode is
  >   enabled, the minor mode indicator `,` appears in the mode line.
- Change the syntax class of uppercase letters to something other than word-constituent.  To do that, use function [`modify-syntax-entry`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Functions.html).  For example, this changes uppercase letter `A` to be in symbols but not words:

  ```
  (modify-syntax-entry ?A "_") ; Give `A` symbol syntax, not word syntax
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted your answer, since it solved my problem for now, but I'm planning to set a lot of characters except English alphabet and numbers as word boundaries as well.  Is there a way to add all the non-English irrelevant characters to the modify-syntax-entry at once?

Comment: At once? Define "*non-English irrelevant characters*". If you can list them then use `dolist` to iterate over them. If not, but if you can characterize them using a function, then use the function to iterate over them. And if this answer answers the question you posed, you might consider accepting it. ;-)